# How to add a property table to a form in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I don't have much experience with C# or VS, but I want to add a property table to a form, like this one:
[image]

So that columns are resizable, editable, of different types (e.g. checkbox for boolean) and sortable. How do I do that?

Comment: Is it a Windows Forms project? Where are you getting the data from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a WinForms `Listview` and that should be able to support everything you need. Just add it to the form, change it to  the `View` property to `Details` and then when you add the columns you can set their types as checkbox column etc.
You can either bind it to a datatable or similar or add the data manually by add to it's `Items` property (and you add the other columns data by adding sub items to each item).

I'd suggest trying that out first and then come back with separate questions for anything that you're having problems with.